# Kendo UI stock chart navigator api

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

How change navigator selection from api? Tried:

```
var chart = $("#stock-chart").data('kendoStockChart'),
    select = chart.options.navigator.select;

select.from = '2010/01/01';
select.to = '2012/01/01';
chart.refresh();
```

Example [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4s71ec1w/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know if there is a way without using chart private field, but this solution works in you fiddle:

```
var chart = $("#stock-chart").data('kendoStockChart'),
    select = select = chart._navigator.options.select;

select.from = '2010/01/01';
select.to = '2012/01/01';
chart.refresh();
```

[Updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/4s71ec1w/1/)